# how to checkout a specific single file at a specific timepoint to a different file

Tags: git

I'd like to checkout a copy of a file at from June 15th at 12noon of this year. I was thinking something like this:

```
git checkout file.txt 'master@{2013-06-15 12:00:00}' file-a-week-ago.txt
```

But no dice. Any advice on how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple, use `show` and redirect to the other file:

```
git show 'master@{2013-06-15 12:00:00}':file.txt > file-a-week-ago.txt
```

Comment: thx; I had to add `./` for the copy in current working directory